# Would there be a solid residue left behind from a reaction between NaK and H2O?

Tags: water

I gather the reaction produces Sodium Oxide and Potassium Oxide as well as Hydrogen. Would there be traces of Sodium Oxide and Potassium Oxide left of a cloth that was positioned near the reaction? Thank a ton.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this site](http://worldaccount.basf.com/wa/NAFTA~en_GB/Catalog/ChemicalsNAFTA/doc4/BASF/PRD/30230091/.pdf?urn=urn:documentum:eCommerce_sol_EU:09007bb280047733.pdf):-

> NaK reacts explosively with water to form hydrogen, potassium hydroxide
>   and sodium hydroxide.

[This site](https://www.basf.com/documents/us/en/sustianability/responsible-care/Sodium_Potassium_Alloy_Product_Safety_Summary.pdf) says:-

> NaK is a strong reducing agent. It is corrosive and will react violently with water. The reaction with water will liberate extremely flammable gases potentially causing a fire or explosion.

This [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhqWoeskmgQ) confirms the above fact.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question is yes, there will be residue. Let's look at the chemical reaction/equation: $$\ce{2NaK + 2H2O -> Na2O + K2O + 2H2}$$